# Importing file from email when using Xcode 3.1.4 with iPhone SDK 3.1

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.1

I want to import an csv file in my app. I search but found solution only for iOS 4. So my question is that is their any way of making file sharing enable  and to import file from an email attachment?

2nd if not then what you suggest for importing a csv file in my app when using.

The solution for iOS 4 link is:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/1948/how-integrate-itunes-file-sharing-with-your-ios-app

Comment: i am using Xcode 3.1.4 with iPhone SDK 3.1 can we do this in this for ios 4;

Comment: You should *always* develop with the latest SDK. You might deploy for older iOS versions, though - which will bring the question back on the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this before iOS 4 it was one of the features. You have already said it is possible in iOS 4.

Upgrade to the latest Xcode (3.2.6, or 4 if you want to pay $5, both are used to target iOS 4.3)

You can then set the deployment target to iOS 3.1 but depending on how file sharing is implemented you may have to add in some if statements to hide things from the user which will not work (like file sharing)

Comment: if i develop this facility in iOS4 then will it work on iOS3. i think it will not work on iOS 3

Comment: the problem is i cannot upgrade becoz i am using  mac os x 10.5

Comment: If you develop it in iOS4, then it won't work in iOS3. Then you need to upgrade to 10.6($30 from apple, less on ebay). Unless your mac is PowerPC? in which case your stuck, unless you do a more costly upgrade.